# Convert string to few variables with pattern

Tags: python, string

I am still learning python,
is there any way to convert python string to few variables with defined pattern?

For instance pattern and text:

```
pattern = '{var1},{var2}::{var3}-:{var4}'
string_text = 'test1,test2::test3-:test4'
```

convert to:

```
var1, var2, var3, var4 = magic method convert string_text using pattern
print(var1)  # test1
print(var2)  # test2
print(var3)  # test3
print(var4)  # test4
```

I know there is a possibility to do that kind of action with datetime object:

```
datetime.strptime('1992-12-22', "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Also I can do it with regex (do not need help with this ;) but maybe there is the same method in string object that I just don't know how to use?

I will appreciate any help!

Comment: Nope. String itself doesn't parse anything like strptime and doesn't search for patterns like regex. But if you're sure your separators (here: `,` `::` `-:`) don't show up in the parts (vars), you might play with splitting your string.

Comment: Nope :( ( , :: -: ) separators were just an example to the problem. I have a little nasty but repeatable strings that I have to parse and using this "pattern" method would be the fastest way. So I need to go for regex

Comment: Anyway! Thanks for answer! :)

Comment: No problem and good luck. :) I actually did a lot of string parsing with regexes myself. I can recommend using named groups with descriptive names and `finditer` (if it's multiple patterns in one long string) - it makes writing code a lot easier and you don't have to adjust group numbers if something changes. :)

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out ;) Have a nice day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex to translate your `pattern` into a proper regular expression pattern with named capturing groups, something like `'(?P<var1>.*?),(?P<var2>.*?)::(?P<var3>.*?)-:(?P<var4>.*?)'`, then use that regex to get a dictionary holding the "variables":

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = '{var1},{var2}::{var3}-:{var4}'
>>> string_text = 'test1,test2::test3-:test4'
>>> p = re.sub("\{(.*?)\}", r"(?P<\1>.*?)", pattern)
>>> m = re.match("^" + p + "$", string_text)
>>> m.groupdict()
{'var1': 'test1', 'var2': 'test2', 'var3': 'test3', 'var4': 'test4'}
```

Note that your `pattern` already contains some regex-control-characters. Those seem not to be a problem here, but you might better `re.escape` the `pattern` first and then do the `re.sub` on the escaped pattern: `p = re.sub(r"\\{(.*?)\\}", r"(?P<\1>.*?)", re.escape(pattern))`